# Inserting and updating value in database using DAL from java

Tags: java, database, data-access-layer, dao

I am a beginner in development having knowledge of core Java. So this question may seem little selfish to you. But i really need help. I got the task in a project to insert the source string and the correspondence target string into the DB using the DAL. I am not asking   you to complete the task for me But i don't have  any idea of how to start with DAL and DAO. So if someone can provide any example or any tutorial of a DAL file and DAO file with fetching values and updating values from database, then that'd be a great help for me. Please help.Thanks

Comment: Are you using Hibernate, or something similar?

Comment: Google for 'java dao' and 'java dal' and learn what they are about.  You'll find examples.

Comment: @TonyEnnis i did that already, you try and post you link as answer. I'll accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try googling "[java DAL](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20DAL&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)" and "[Java DAO](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20DAO&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)".  Also [Hibernate](http://www.google.com/search?q=java%20DAO&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is a good start.  I like Hibernate as long as the implementation is kept simple.